# Mask plugin, Atlas composer and Legend

Tags: qgis, print-composer, masking, atlas

I'm tryin' to use the mask plugin associated with atlas composer (QGIS 2.7 dev).
I'd like to have in the legend of map composer only the features that belong to mask instance (inside the mask).
if I select the "green filter" for the Legend elements, there are visible in map composer also the features outside the mask.

Is it possible?